# Why Android seems to execute only the first two lines on my method

Tags: java, android

I have a method below when I call it only the first two lines are executed what could be the reason, am testing this on android 9 any help where lg is a button, pr is a progressbar all are correctly initialised. What suprises me is that the method that does the opposite of this one works pretty well please help, This method is called from within an android's javascriptInterface method which inside an inner class:

```
public void retry() {
       pr.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       lg.setEnabled(true); 
       lg.setText("Retry"); 
}
```

retry(); was called from processesContent() which has the annotation -> @JavascriptInterface like below:

```
final class IJavascriptHandler {
    
    IJavascriptHandler(Context c) {
      
        mContext = c;
    }

    //API 17 and higher required you to add @JavascriptInterface as mandatory before your method.
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void processContent(String string)
    {
       // Toast.makeText(Settings.this,string,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      if(string.equals("user not found")){
          retry();
      }
       }
}
```

All this was made possible by using the below code in webviewClient

```
 @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            { 
                view.loadUrl("javascript:window.Android.processContent(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerText);");
          
            }
```

Its seems to me the problem merges from calling methods inside a method with the annotation @JavascriptInterface, am saying this because the same method works fine when called from other methods, please help,Also I really have to use the the JavascriptInteface unless if there is better way please advise me

Comment: You can try to use ->lg.setText("Retry");   before the ->lg.setEnabled(true);   May be ..

Comment: I already tried putting lg.setText("Retry"); first and each of the 3 lines has been put first but only the first 2 are excecuted I really wonder why

Comment: Please also show the xml file and other functions that are changing the UI as it is impossible to see the state of `lg` or the other attributes set on it. Also please show the exact function which you say is working.